# "Correcting" british to american english

Tags: discussion

In regard to:
[Can I be fired the same day that I hand in my notice?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/149421/90889)

In [revision 6](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/149421/revisions) 'endeavours' was changed to 'endeavors' which I think is strange especially as this is a UK question and this is the correct spelling in british english for what I know.

Are we enforcing american english or was this part of the edit superflous?

Comment: Keep in mind how much inline spelling checkers and auto-correct have to do with this.  They'll flag a spelling from a different locale the same as a true misspelling, so editors may not realize what they did.

Answer (score 55):

The general reference to use on this subject is on main meta: [What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23869/260382)

Overal consensus is that while **tags should use US English** to remain consistent, "correcting" one version of English to another is not recommended. Typically the **style used by the OP should be preserved**. Whether it's worth rejecting an otherwise good edit over US/GB spelling changes is a matter of opinion and typically situational.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and I think the guideline is sensible. I would argue a rejection of the edit is not necessary, still I would restore the original spelling.

Answer (score 23):

The picture says it all.

[image]

Comment: While funny, this statement is factually incorrect. British English has changed just as much as American English has since the day they were separated!

Comment: Am I making a mistake when I say "armour" then? Or is it the other way around? I'm confused.

Comment: It's pickle, not gurkin. Get it right, brits.

Comment: So I am from New Zealand, where English spelling (i.e., Office spell check) is closer to British English. However I prefer American English spelling, as it is closer to spoken (most) NZ/US/UK English. I.e., American English spelling has followed the spoken language evolution more closely. (That's my 10¢ anyway)

Comment: I feel conflicted about whether or not to upvote this. D:

Comment: @Qix "Gherkin", not "gurkin"...  Which is a pickled cucumber, as opposed to a pickled onion, pickled egg, mixed pickles, lime pickle, South Asian pickle ("achaar") or Branston pickle.  Gherkin are *a* pickle, but more specific.

Answer (score 6):

You would not be "Correcting" it. You would be "Translating". Since the rules don't specify which dialect of english one should use, I would ignore any variant unless its truly causing a problem (e.g. if it was in an obscure pidgin dialect)

Answer (score -5):

I made the change, and it was **not** with any intention to resolve any *conflict of usage*, just my personal choice.

Free free to revert it, if you please.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I can not revert because of the rep limit (I could put it in a queue). Thanks for your statement and please understand that I did not want to attack you personally as I was pretty sure there was no intention to offend anyone in this case. Still I felt that this needed to be adressed.

Comment: @KamiKaze I completely understand and no offense taken. We're part of a community, and discussion is a healthy thing.

Comment: Your "personal choice"? In the chat on the original question you said "Neither of those are my first language, and so far I did not think it as a big deal to use either of them. I myself sometimes use those interchangeably.". I must say that your grasp of English is very impressive for someone who has learnt it as a second language! One of the subtleties of the various dialects, which might not be initially apparent, is that the differences in spelling are quite a big deal for a lot of native speakers. For example "colour" is **_wrong_** in the US, as "color" is **_wrong_** in the UK... [1/2]

Comment: ...if you miscorrect one to the other, then you make the OP look like a bit of an idiot: someone who doesn't even know how to use their own language! In the case of the linked question, the OP really didn't need any extra help in that department - their situation already painted quite a picture :-D - so your edit did them a disservice, in my view. One thing that can help, if you feel like, is to add other dialects' dictionaries to your browser, so that correct spellings in other dialects won't get underlined in red. [2/2]

Comment: @AaronF As a matter of fact, English is my fourth language (in order of educational subject), and while I try my best, I cannot guarantee that I'm 100% correct at any time. Sorry for the confusion, but it was never intended, it's just something I made as a part of the whole edit. I thought communication is meant for communicating the concept / idea, not about exact grammar - at least, not on this site where we have diverse population. Anyways, apologies one again and now the change is reverted anyways.

Comment: @AaronF how is the third comment in anyway connected to the topic?

Comment: In no way whatsoever - it's an aside, hence the parentheses - it was just something that popped into my head while writing the previous comments

Comment: (as another aside: I don't understand why the downvote-o-tron has weighed so heavily in on this answer. Do up/down votes on Meta SE sites have different significance?)

Comment: @AaronF Yes, votes in meta usually shows agreement / disagreement.

Comment: @AaronF aren't you being more than a a bit harsh?

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica I might be being, yes, though if I am then it's not due to malicious intent, let me assure you. I made a concerted effort to try and keep the tone of my messages light, respectful, and good-humoured. I really didn't want to have a go at Sourav for this, because I can see that he had the best of intentions. (To which message in particular are you referring, btw? If it's about the "billion" aside, then no, not sorry! But regarding the other two, then yes, please let me know if I inadvertently crossed the line with something I said.)

Comment: I write in Australian English (very close to UK English). I prefer to read UK English than US English because some spellings and grammar are wrong or sound very different from what I'm used to. I understand I have no right to change another person's correct spelling and grammar (where they come from). What's more disconcerting than US English is a mixture of UK & US English. However, you have to be careful because Canadian English is in between US & and UK English! You have no personal choice in another user's correct spelling. It _is_ a big deal!

Comment: I went ahead and edited your answer. Not my intention to imply there was anything wrong with it, just my personal choice. Feel free to revert if you feel.

Comment: I think it's unfair to be negative towards Sourav for this, I've often caught myself nearly correcting someones AmE whilst editing a post. I'm assuming it wasn't the main reason for the edit. It's especially easy to do without thinking when you have spell check set one way or the other

Comment: It seems wrong to edit a correct spelling to the same word in a different dialect just because of personal preference.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica Seriously, what is wrong with you all folks? Once again, I'm repeating: I made the edit because I tried improving the post, and the choice of the spelling was my own - **I did not make the change only to enforce my personal choice on the spelling**. I will seriously re-consider editing posts going forward.

Comment: @Sourav Perhaps I misunderstood your point from your answer in this Meta question, but it sounded very much like you edited the spelling out of personal preference. Your latest comment sounds like that isn't the case.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica Thanks for the response, and sorry for appearing a bit impatient in my previous comment. The point is, as I mentioned, I'm not a native English speaker, and neither am I inclined to enforce any particular language type. I was making the overall edit as usual, and part of that was changing the spelling in question. I unknowingly followed the standard guideline (as mentioned in the highest voted answer), but again, it was not to enforce any one dialect over the other. The choice of spelling was my choice, but the intention was not to change the dialect. That's all.